# Fix SSL negotiation failed

Tags: apache, perl, ssl, centos

I installed : "cpan isntall Crypt::SSLeay" So the error from "fs.cgi: ERROR 500 SSL negotiation failed:" Changed to "
failed while requesting fs.cgi: SSL negotiation failed: at /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 25 at /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 25
"

How to fix this? I searched this forum but the issue is still there. I have two servers first server is accessing the server 2, both have different ssl certificates.

Apache on CentOS 6. Please explain the solution properly.

Comment: Please run your code with `perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4 program.pl` and edit your question to include the output from this.

Comment: [root@srv685 ~]# perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4 program.pl
Can't open perl script "program.pl": No such file or directory

Comment: You should of course replace `program.pl` with your actual  name of the program causing this error. I have no idea how this is named.

Comment: Hey are you on Skype, we need this to get fixed. I will pay you.

Comment: No, I will not do this. Try to put the necessary details here so that all can help instead. Apart from that: don't use Crypt::SSLeay (old, insecure, some TLS features unsupported). Use Net::SSLeay and IO::Socket::SSL and a new version of LWP instead.

Comment: Well after you solve it you can post the solution here.

Comment: still no. My guess is that you have some very old system with an old LWP, using Crypt::SSLeay (old, insecure, missing features) and this is causing the problems. Try to use current LWP with IO::Socket::SSL instead. And if it does not work make a minimal example on how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Okay, I installed : "cpan isntall Crypt::SSLeay" 
So the error from "fs.cgi: ERROR 500 SSL negotiation failed:" 
Changed to
"failed while requesting fs.cgi: SSL negotiation failed: at /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 25 at /usr/local/share/perl5/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 25" 
----
CentOS 6, and LWP, and all were isntalled yesterday so I think they are all updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136492/discussion-between-steffen-ullrich-and-theradbrad).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed by opening port 443 on both servers.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to problem in SSL. Some SSL certificates won't be enabled to cover the emails. Or in your server the devocot or imap was not installed to connect SSL. I experience the same problem and its fixed by simply turning off the SSL or make it to TLS to connect the email it fixed. May be this solution help someone in future